# XML sitemap redirects to HTML sitemap after change

Tags: magento-1.7, xml, htaccess, sitemaps, mod-rewrite

I have a strange issue where when you visit `www.website.com/sitemap.xml` or `www.website.ca/sitemap.xml`, it shows the sitemap as an html page.

The following has been added to my `.htaccess` :

```
#Sitemap: https://www.website.ca/sitemaps/ca/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.ca
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemaps/ca/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]

#Sitemap: https://www.website.com/sitemaps/usa/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemaps/usa/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]
```

Is this normal?

Comment: Please confirm your Magento version? You have mentioned Magento2 and Magento-1.9 both.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I am using Magento 1.7 actually, my mistake